# The set of all vectors of the form $(a-4b,5,4a+b,-a-b)$ is not a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

This isn't homework, it's test review. Will someone tell me if my analysis is correct?

The answer is D (not a vector space) because the zero vector is not possible.  Setting $a = 0$ and $b = 0$ makes the vector $(0,5,0,0)$. **It is closed under scalar multiplication and vector addition, though, correct?**

EDIT:  It is not closed under vector addition and scalar multiplication because the 2nd component must always be $5$, and scalar would scale that, and addition would sum $5 + 5 = 10$, etc... So it fails all three tests, correct?

> [image: problem]

**The answer from the answer key is D.**

Comment: Using all caps is considered shouting on the internet, and is quite rude. Please don't ever do it again.

Comment: Thanks; sorry.  I wanted my edit to be emphasized.  Anyway, how did you add the border to the image?

Comment: Yes, you are right, it fails to be a vector space in many ways.

Comment: @eestack: Starting a paragraph with `>` puts it in a blockquote. This is part of the `markdown` syntax of the website.

Comment: I appreciate your edits and direction for proper formatting on this site. :)  Thank you Andre for confirmation!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your answer is correct, $W$ is not closed under scalar multiplication and is not closed under vector addition.  $W$ does not contain the zero vector, and this can be seen by setting the defining vector equal to the zero vector.  The second element gives the equation 5 = 0 which is impossible.

Comment: Great, I feel more confident now.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't contain the $0$ vector, regardless of the values of $a$ and $b$. It's important to not just consider $a = 0$ and $b = 0$, as the zero vector could conceivably come from other values of $a$ and $b$. For example, in $\mathbb{R}^2$, vectors of the form $(a - 1, a - 1)$ are a subspace, and you get the $0$ vector by plugging in $a = 1$, not $a = 0$.

The set of vectors in your question also is not closed under addition or scalar multiplication. The second coordinate is fixed to $5$, so the sum of any two vectors in this set will produce a vector whose second coordinate is $10$, and hence automatically out of the set. Additionally, if you scale the vector by some $\lambda \neq 1$, then the resultant vector will have a second component of $5\lambda \neq 5$, and again will not be in the set.

However, you should also know that, in order to justify why this isn't a vector space, you need only come up with one counterexample, or prove $0$ is not in the set. You can just pick two specific vectors in the space and add them, or one specific vector in the space and scale it. Then show the result is not in the space.

Hope that helps!